# Looking for a third party photo gallery

Tags: html, css, flash, photoshop

Does anyone know of a easy to install photo gallery. I'm assuming it would have to be flash. I want to implement it on my own site. I am looking for the one that is thumbnails,and when you click a thumbnail, it expands and you can navigate through the other photos. Or something like that

The ones I have found want me to submit my mysql db password and login. Not comfortable with that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable with html then [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks alot. That was so easy and is SUPER sweet! Hope I am not asking you too much, but I was curious if you knew of a add-on or plug-in for the light box that crops my full sized images and makes the links thumbnails. Right now I am doing a makeshift version. I have made duplicates of my images,one thumb size and one big, and make display image(the thumb) the link that you hit that activates the box. That works fine, but its double the work I have to do, and would be great to have it done automatically. This is all new to me and I really appreciate your time

Comment: Try using Galleria, it's a fully featured gallery solution and allows either lightbox (http://galleria.aino.se/media/galleria/demos/lightbox-02.html) or galleries (http://galleria.aino.se/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Photoshop then 
go to file>automate>web Photo gallery>there are some options according to your requirement.